# Do I have to use the exact same variables in each step, if I have a two-step propensity score match followed by a regression?

Tags: regression, sample, predictor, propensity-scores, matching

I am using the propensity score match to grow my sample based on a smaller dataset of existing units that received the treatment. The match will find more likely units from its large population that received treatment which I can manually review and add to my sample. I can also grow my untreated sample from this match followed by manual review. Because of this, my method does not necessarily have to be a propensity score match as long as some form of matching can be done.

But say I were to do the propensity score match followed by a regression. Currently my dependent variable is a binary whether it received treatment or not.

1. Do I need to use the exact same covariates between both phases?
2. Does my dependent variable need to differ between the two stages?
3. Is it redundant to do a regression after the match?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. In general, propensity scores can use many more variables than the regression phase. They certainly do not have to be the same variables. In fact, often, the propensity score will be a variable in the regression, substituting for the variables that went into it. (This is a variation that I don't think qualifies exactly as "matching"; I'm not up to date on the literature for when to prefer propensity score as a covariate vs. using it to match, but both are done).
2. Yes. Otherwise, what are you doing?  The point of propensity scoring is to try to account for variables in the data that relate to one's propensity to do something. One example is job training and its effect on income. The problem is that people who choose to get job training are likely to have lower incomes and be different in many ways from those who do not. So, for the propensity score phase, the DV would be "gets training" and for the regression phase it would be "income".
3. No. That's often the point of doing the match.